# Regex to exclude match

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this has been asked before, but I just couldn't get mine to work. Using this example, Im trying to get the template variable but not if its used in some kind of tag.

```
{{ callMe() }}

<img src="{{ callMe() }}" />
```

Should match the first one, `{{ callMe() }}` but not the second. Ive been tinkering with negative lookahead, but not sure if i understand it. Here's my regex. Can anyone please have a look. Thanks.

```
(?!<.+\/?>)(({{.*([\w\.]+)\(.*\).*}}))
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZXU8RM/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Could you tag language which you use to regex? There is many regex versions.

Comment: @LeszekMazur I edited the tag. Its for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!<.*){{.*([\w\.]+)\(.*\).*}}(?!.*>)
```

Need to check there's no `<` before and no `>` after

```
(?<!<[^>]*){{.*([\w\.]+)\(.*\).*}}(?![^<]*>)
```

would also check for `<p>{{ callMe() }}</p>`